# How to calculate time difference between two given time in xslt?

Tags: xslt

Given below is the xml.

I want to display time difference like: "2h 52m".

START TIME - 09:02

STOP TIME - 11:45

TOTAL -2h 52m

```xml
<Surgery>
   <SURGERY_START_TIME>9:02</SURGERY_START_TIME>
   <SURGERY_STOP_TIME>11:45</SURGERY_STOP_TIME>
</Surgery>
```

I tried the below code but that doesn't work,

```xml
<xsl:variable name="surgStartTime">
        <xsl:value-of select="SURGERY_START_TIME/."/>
</xsl:variable>
<xsl:variable name="surgStopTime">
        <xsl:value-of select="SURGERY_STOP_TIME/."/>
</xsl:variable>
<xsl:value-of select="$surgStartTime -$surgStopTime)/>
```

Comment: You can do computations on proper `xs:time`s e.g. `xs:time('09:02:00') - xs:time('11:45:00')` but the result is not 2h52m I think but 2h43m. So before you do time arithmetics you will need to fix the input (e.g. with regular expressions) to get the right format for `xs:time`.

Comment: Which version of XSLT does your processor support?

Comment: Hi thank you. I think <xsl:stylesheet version="1.0">

Comment: Can you please show an example, how to apply regular expression on the input 9:02 and 11:45?

Comment: That does not answer my question. See here how to test your processor: https://stackoverflow.com/a/25245033/3016153. If it only supports XSLT 1.0 then you cannot use time arithmetic or regex.

Comment: ok. I just checked...my processor supports xslt 1.0, but can I use xs:time if not regular expressions?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

There is no support for date/time arithmetic in XSLT 1.0; you need to do the calculation yourself - e.g:

```
<xsl:stylesheet version="1.0" 
xmlns:xsl="http://www.w3.org/1999/XSL/Transform">
<xsl:output method="xml" version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8" indent="yes"/>

<xsl:template match="Surgery">
    <!-- calculate the duration in minutes -->
    <xsl:variable name="duration" select="60 * substring-before(SURGERY_STOP_TIME, ':') + substring-after(SURGERY_STOP_TIME, ':') - 60 * substring-before(SURGERY_START_TIME, ':') - substring-after(SURGERY_START_TIME, ':')" />
    <xsl:copy>
        <xsl:copy-of select="*"/>
        <DURATION>
            <!-- output whole hours -->
            <xsl:value-of select="floor($duration div 60)"/>
            <xsl:text>h </xsl:text>
            <!-- output remaining minutes -->
            <xsl:value-of select="$duration mod 60"/>
            <xsl:text>m</xsl:text>
        </DURATION>
    </xsl:copy>
</xsl:template>

</xsl:stylesheet>
```

Applied to your input example, the result will be:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<Surgery>
   <SURGERY_START_TIME>9:02</SURGERY_START_TIME>
   <SURGERY_STOP_TIME>11:45</SURGERY_STOP_TIME>
   <DURATION>2h 43m</DURATION>
</Surgery>
```

and not `2h 52m` as stated in your question.